# Installing Forever in Debian Lenny (5.0) via NPM - error

Tags: linux, node.js, debian, lenny, forever

I'm trying to install forever via NPM, on Debian Lenny (5.0) but **I am receiving the following error during installation, that starts with:**

```
> node-waf configure build

npm ERR! TypeError: options.uid should be a number
```

I've tried Googling - but got nothing useful, except **I stumbled across [this pastebin page](http://pastebin.com/ZHc831tS)** with the exact same error which some other poor soul was getting too.

**Any Node/forever people out there know what might be going wrong?**

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to install using an old npm version. Try using [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm).

**Note: Please use curl/wget command to install nvm.**

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.31.0/install.sh | bash
```

install a 4+ node version.

```
nvm install v5.11.0
nvm use v5.11.0
```

So run:

```
npm install -g forever
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  We've since dropped forever in favour of [pm2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2), which we are happier with.